# Multiple upload images in active_admin with Active Storage

Tags: activeadmin, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I found useful article about uploading image using Active Storage in activeadmin: https://medium.com/@maris.cilitis/using-ruby-on-rails-active-storage-image-uploads-for-active-admin-backed-resources-5638a9ca0b46

But how to upload multiple images in activeadmin with Active Storage the same way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need do some changes

model:

```
has_many_attached :images
```

instead of

```
has_one_attached :image
```

activeadmin:

```
permit_params images: []

form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :images, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }
  end
end
```

and you'll can choose many files to upload

Comment: it works after I removed this line `input_html: { multiple: true }` and added `form  :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|`

Comment: The issue with this is that we don't have the option to keep the selected images on edit page. Each time we go to edit page we need to select all the images.
Is there a way to pass the old selected images here

Comment: @NidhinSG you can borrow ideas from the solution posted by edariedl here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71990425/rails-active-storage-keep-existing-files-uploads

Answer (score 3):

This works for me, upload and show of multiple images in active_admin using ActiveStorage.

```ruby
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  permit_params :content, images: []

  form html: { multipart: true } do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :content
      f.input :images, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }
    end

    f.actions
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :content
      row :images do
        div do
          post.images.each do |img|
            div do
              image_tag url_for(img), size: "200x200"
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```